# Integrate an existence user database with microsoft identity?

Tags: database, asp.net-identity, microsoft-identity-platform

I am a new developer and have to do a complete code rewrite in an existing project.

There is already a database for users which was made a long time ago.

I wanted to know if it was possible to integrate microsoft identity without too much problem and have all the functionality of it without needing to create a new user table and the same column names.
I already have the username and password columns, but I don't have EmailConfirmed, etc.

Thank you in advance for your answers

Comment: If I were you I'd just create the new table in the standard format Identity expects and then migrate users from one table to the other. The only issue I see is making sure that the passwords (hashes) are in the right format for Identity to understand. I think you'll have more trouble trying to make Identity work with your custom table

Comment: @Xerillio Ok thanks for the answer, that was the conclusion I had made